# VB6 Apps Hangs only in Vista/Win7/Win2008 Must reboot to bring them back

Tags: vb6, windows-7, windows-server-2008, windows-vista

I have vb6 apps that runs without any problems for hours on Vista 32/64-bit or win7 32/64-bit and XP 32/64-bit machines.  It sometimes hang in XP machines, but I can just close the app in Task Manager then restart without any problems.

Now with Vista/Win7, it still hangs after several hours then I close the apps with Task Manager then restart the app.  App will start but will hang at the same app location just as if it remembered where it hang before.  The only way to bring the App back is to reboot the computer.

Did anyone experienced this before?  I know this VB6 apps could be doing bunch of junk and not releasing memory and etc.  But if i close the app in Task Manager, shouldn't it come back as before?

Comment: You might take this as a hint...

Comment: Does it run ok if you just logoff/logon instead of rebooting?

Comment: no.. must reboot to get it to work.  thats the part i dont get.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it might be hanging somewhere in VBRUN6.DLL, the Visual Basic 6 Runtime Library, which would explain the need to reboot, since the DLL is not unloading.  I have no clue about what your app is doing to cause this, though.  And I fear that any such analysis here on SO is going to be out of scope, unless the program is trivially simple.

Comment: I agree.  Nowhere near enough detail provided and it sounds as if it can happen on almost any version of Windows.

Comment: I know.. Hard to provide detailed info as it is not a simple program. Very complicated plant control program.  My suspect at the moment is Data Access: it is using RDO 2.0 to access SQL2005/2008 servers.
Fact that it "worked-Taskmanager Kill-restartApp" prior to Vista is what i am trying to get at.  It does run in Vista+.. Just when it hangs, i can not restart w/o reboot.

Comment: If this is a mission-critical program, it might make sense to rewrite it in a more modern venue...say VB.NET, Winforms and ADO.NET.

Comment: Microsoft's support statement for vb6 is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788708.aspx